# How to change the size of a subplot using Axes object (without gs)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Been trying to figure out how to change the size of a subplot in Matplotlib when using the Axes object. Say you setup some plot

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax=np.empty((2,2,),dtype=object)
ax[0][0]=fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax[0][1]=fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax[1][0]=fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax[1][1]=fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)
```

Now say you'd like to change the size of one of these subplots. I've seen instances where you use gs to do so, but curious if there was another method without gs. It looks like you can use get_position with set_position?

```
old_position=ax[0][0].get_position()
old_position[-1]=old_position[-1]/2
ax[0][0].set_position(old_position)
```

The idea here was just to squish the top left plot by half its original size. However the position object returned is a BBox object that is not subscriptable, and I cannot see a way of "subscripting it" so the old position can be changed and a new one set.

Any suggestions on how to change the size of one of the subplots using the get/set position?

Comment: The `Bbox` object has a bounds property.  You can modify those numbers and pass them back to `set_position` https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Bbox.bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7153123/12131013), you can get the indexable coordinates using `Axes.get_position().bounds`. You can then update the coordinates from that result and use the `Axes.set_position()` as you were trying to do.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax_coords = list(ax[0,0].get_position().bounds)
ax_coords[-1] /= 2
ax[0, 0].set_position(ax_coords)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The bounds property is what I was missing.